# Attribute dependencies between two classes

Tags: java, constructor, dependencies

I want to code a little text adventure/dungeon crawler type of game. At the moment I have the classes `Creature`, `Player`, and `Enemy`. The classes `Player` and `Enemy` are subclasses of `Creature`.

I want to make the level of the enemy dependent on the level of the player. So for example, the enemy's level should always be 1 level above the player's level. So when the player is level 4 you should only be able to face enemies which are level 5.

My idea was to put something like this in the constructor of the `Enemy` class:

```
 public Enemy(String name, int hp, int atk, int exp) {
    super(name, Player.getLevel + 1, hp, atk);
    this.exp = exp;
 }
```

But that is clearly not allowed. Now I have no idea how to achieve this result. I lack some basic understanding of Java, but I'm willing to learn.

My code looks like this at the moment. I left the getters and setters out for better readability.

```
public class Creature {

   private String name;
   private int    level;
   private int    hp;
   private int    atk;

   public Creature (String name, int level, int hp, int atk){
      this.name = name;
      this.level = level;
      this.hp = hp;
      this.atk = atk;
   }
}


public class Player extends Creature {

   private int currentEXP;
   private int expBar;

   public Player(String name) {
      super(name, 1, 100, 10);
      this.currentEXP = 0;
      this.expBar = 50;
   }
}


public class Enemy extends Creature {

   int exp;

   public Enemy(String name, int level, int hp, int atk, int exp) {
      super(name, level, hp, atk);
      this.exp = exp;
   }
}
```

Comment: Wow that answer came quick!
Thank you very much, I think I understand now what my problem was.
I have to create an instance of my player object first, which I can then pass to the constructor of the enemy class. That makes sense!
Thanks for the quick reply. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `private` modifier makes `level` unavailable in the subclasses. To solve that, you can either make change `private` to `protected` (or nothing / default), or you can provide an accessible getter method (`int getLevel() { return level; }`).

Your `Enemy` constructor takes a `level` argument, so to implement the `player level + 1` feature, you can simply pass `player.getLevel() + 1`, alternatively pass `player.getLevel()` and let the constructor take care of adding 1.

The method using these classes (assuming `main` for now) would look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    Player p = new Player("Player1");  
    Enemy e = new Enemy("Enemy1", p.getLevel() + 1, 100, 10, 40);  
}
```

To clarify, the reason why `Player.getLevel + 1` doesn't work is because `Player` is a class, but you need a `Player` **object** (i.e. the result of calling `new Player(...)`) to refer to instance fields or methods, such as `getLevel`.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed that you said "left the getters and setters out for better readability". You can ignore the first part, I guess.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, that made a lot of things clearer now.
Have a nice day!